# Binary Tree Line by Line Level Order Traversal Time Complexity

Tags: data-structures, queue, time-complexity, binary-tree

Here is the Code of Level Order Traversal Line by Line. How come the Time Complexity is O(n) and not O(n2).

def levelOrder(root):

```
queue = [root]

while len(queue):
    count = len(queue)
    while count:
        current = queue.pop(0)
        print(current.data,end='\t')
        if current.left:
            queue.append(current.left)
        if current.right:
            queue.append(current.right)

        count -= 1
    print()
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX9AZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by O(n2) you actually mean O(n^2).

Why should it be O(n^2)? Just because you have two nested loops it doesn't mean that the complexity is O(n^2). It all depends what you are iterating over and what you are doing inside the loop.

If you look at the execution of the code, you'll see every node in the tree is inserted and popped exactly once, and every iteration of the loop is productive (so there are no iterations that don't do anything). Therefore, the number of iterations is bounded by N, the number of nodes in the tree. So the overall complexity is O(N).

Answer (score -1):

No this has only O(N*L) complexity, where N - number of nodes and L - number of level tree has. I explaining why:

```
         Assume tree has N nodes

         queue = [root]         | O(1)

         while len(queue):       | size of level tree has : O(Level)

         count = len(queue)     | O(1) 

         while count:            | it roughly depends number nodes are left after 
                                 | processing left and right sub-tree of the current 
                                 | node; O(Left sub tree nodes) + O(Right sub tree 
                                   nodes) => O(L+R) => O(N)
                    
         count -= 1             | O(1)
```

In terms of upper bound of an algorithm, it wrap into O(N * L * 1) => O(N*L), where is N-Number of Nodes and L-Number of Level, tree has.